# Five further sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my second batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; 
yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   18, 17, 18, 22, 26, 35, 32, 32, ??, 38, ??, 52, ??, ??, ??, 64, ...

---

> Sequence 2:
>   Du, Me, Ph, Me, Al, Mi, ??

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ..., 14, 13, 14, 6, 7, 12, 8, 16, 9, 13, 10, 15, 11, 12, ??, 6, ??, 2, ??, ??

---

> Sequence 4:
>   1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, ?, ?, ?, ...

---

> Sequence 5:
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, M, A, J, ?, H, T, P, T, F, P, B, L, J, G, H, G, A, C, H, C, ?, R, T, W, H, C, ...

Comment: You guys are really fast! I thought these would take much longer to solve...

Comment: Since sequence 2 has been solved last, I count it as the most difficult one of the five sequences and I assign the "correct answer" sign to Julian Rosen's answer.

Comment: I made a CW answer combining all of the solutions. It might be more useful to have that as the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sequence 1

> Number of matches played in the FIFA World Cups:
>     **18**, **17**, **18**, **22**, **26**, **35**, **32**, **32**, **32**, **38**, **38**, **52**, **52**, **52**, **52**, **64**,...
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup#Attendance)

Sequence 2

> Stars in the Big Dipper (the seven brightest stars in the constellation Ursa Major):
>      **Du**bhe, **Me**rak, **Ph**ecda, **Me**grez, **Al**ioth, **Mi**zar, **Al**kaid
> [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Dipper#Stars)

Sequence 3

> Popes:
>      ..., Benedict XIV (**14**), Clement XIII (**13**), Clement XIV (**14**), Pius VI (**6**), Pius VII (**7**), Leo XII (**12**), Pius VIII (**8**), Gregory XVI (**16**), Pius IX (**9**), Leo XIII (**13**), Pius X (**10**), Benedict XV (**15**), Pius XI (**11**), Pius XII (**12**), John XXIII (**23**), Paul VI (**6**), John Paul I (**1**), John Paul II (**2**), Benedict XVI (**16**), Francis I (**1**)
> [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popes)

Sequence 4

> Number of strokes needed to write Roman numerals:
>      I (**1**), II (**2**), III (**3**), IV (**3**), V (**2**), VI (**3**), VII (**4**), VIII (**5**), IX (**3**), X (**2**), XI (**3**), XII (**4**), XIII (**5**), XIV (**5**), XV (**4**), XVI (**5**), XVII (**6**), XVIII (**7**),...

Sequence 5

> Presidents of the United States:
>     **W**ashington, **A**dams, **J**efferson, **M**adison, **M**onroe, **A**dams, **J**ackson, **V**an Buren, **H**arrison, **T**yler, **P**olk, **T**aylor, **F**illmore, **P**ierce, **B**uchanan, **L**incoln, **J**ohnson, **G**rant, **H**ayes, **G**arfield, **A**rthur, **C**leveland, **H**arrison, **C**leveland, **M**cKinley, **R**oosevelt, **T**aft, **W**ilson, **H**arding, **C**oolidge,...
> [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States)

Answer (score 8):

Sequence 2 is

> the initial two letters of the names of the stars in the Big Dipper (the seven brightest stars in the constellation Ursa Major). The stars are:
>  Dubhe
>  Merak
> Phecda
>  Megrez
> Alioth
> Mizar
> Alkaid
> The missing letters are 'Al'.
> I first noticed that sequence 2 was much shorter than the others, having only seven items. I did a Google search for 'things that come in sevens', and one of the lists mentioned there were seven stars in the Big Dipper. I looked up the names of the stars, and found they were a match.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer (naturally):

Sequence 1:

> Number of matches played in the FIFA World Cups since 1930. Missing entries are 32, 38, 52, 52, 52. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup#Attendance)

Answer (score 7):

Sequence 5 is

> Presidents of the United States.
>  W(ashington), A(dams), J(efferson), M(adison), M(onroe), A(dams), J(ackson), V(an Buren), H(arrison), T(yler), P(olk), T(aylor), F(illmore), P(ierce), B(uchanan), L(incoln), J(ohnson), G(rant), H(ayes), G(arfield), A(rthur), C(leveland), H(arrison), C(leveland), M(cKinley), R(oosevelt), T(aft), W(ilson), H(arding), C(oolidge).
>  The sequence ends here, but the presidents continue: H(oover), R(oosevelt), T(ruman), E(isenhower), K(ennedy), J(ohnson), N(ixon), F(ord), C(arter), R(eagan), B(ush), C(linton), B(ush), O(bama). 
>  The missing letters are W, A, J, M, V, M.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: Pretty much a lucky guess.

Answer (score 6):

Sequences 1, 3, and 4 again can be googled:

Sequence 1:

> Goles totales in mismunidales = Number of goals scored at the Soccer World Championships
>  18 17 18 22 26 35 32 32 32 38 38 52 52 64 64 64

Sequence 3:

> The numbering of the popes,
>  ending with John XXIII, Paul VI, John Paul I, John Paul 2, Benedict XVI, Francis I:
>  ..., 14, 13, 14, 6, 7, 12, 8, 16, 9, 13, 10, 15, 11, 12, 23, 6, 1, 2, 16, 1

Sequence 4:

> number of strokes in the Roman numerals: I, II, III, IV, ...
>  1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7

Comment: BTW, your interpretation of sequence 1 is wrong.

Comment: @dmg: I see.  Google showed me the number sequence on some page in Spanish, and I only understood that the numbers are somehow from the soccer world cup.

Comment: Same here. Just crosschecked in Wikipedia what exactly about the world cup did those number say :D